# Не получается запустить приложение с firebase на ios, на android все нормально

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firestore

Не получается запустить приложение с firebase на ios, на android все нормально.

Конфигурация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Query#addSnapshotListener on channel plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:159:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:12)
#2      MethodChannelQuery.snapshots.<anonymous closure> (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_query.dart:55:50)
#3      _runGuarded (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:847:24)
#4      _BroadcastStreamController._subscribe (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:213:7)
#5      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:860:19)
#6      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:493:9)
#7      new _ForwardingStreamSubscription (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:118:10)
#8      _Forwardin
```

Comment: Попробуйте в терминале: `flutter clean` и `flutter packages get`

Comment: @MiTпробовал не помогло

Comment: попробуйте поднять на последнюю версию, у вас довольно старая версия стоит. И если не поможет сделайте это: `rm ios/Podfile`, `rm ios/podfile.lock` и `flutter run`